Flow error. The flow failed to access the value ServiceDate because it hasn't been set or assigned
I am bulding a flow that has to do the following:

If an opportunity is updated to Stage "Won" it has to check for its OpportunityLineItems
If one of the OpportunityLineItems is effective in the time another OpportunityLineItem from the same related account it should return an error and wouldn't be allowed to be saved
The time interval where the OpportunityLineItem is effective is defined by ServiceDate and EffectiveDate (Start and end of period)

The flow is returning "The flow failed to access the value ServiceDate because it hasn't been set or assigned". I don't know why it is returning that error as the OpportunityLineItem already exists and the date not set in the flow, it already has a value

Have you confirmed that you are actually retrieving the ServiceDate field before you look to use it within the logic in the Flow? This kind of error is common if you aren't using the option for Salesforce to automatically retrieve all fields.

There was one of the GetRecords that where I wasn0t storing all the fields. I thought I had removed it. it seems to be solved. Thanks!
